# Articles when describing commercial logos

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I shoot stock photography and sometimes I post pictures showing logos of business corporations. Usually I use a phrase like "The logo of Orange S.A., a French telecommunications company" etc. Is this form correct or should I use " A logo of Orange ... "? And in case if "a logo of Orange" is preferred - is using "the" in this context a grammatical error or just less popular but correct expression?

Comment: How many logos does Orange have?

Comment: It's common for companies to have a number for different situations, that all differ slightly.

Comment: "one of the" might be appropriate instead of "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "the" or "a" in reference to a company's logo depends on circumstance.

In the first place, we assume that a company has designed only one logo for their business.  Given that assumption, most instances would require "the" to identify that which is specific to one company.

Logos may appear in a multitude of viewable circumstance.  Say for instance, a photo of a specific subject also happens to have captured the logo in the frame, then the acknowledgement might be "a".  For example, a caption for a photo of irony might describe the subject and note that there is a logo of opposition in the background.

> Man enjoys a Coca-Cola, standing in front of a Pepsi logo.

When the subject of the photo is a logo, use "the" if the logo is identified specifically to its owner.

Usually, "a" will mean one of several/many and "the" is specific.